# Copy array of strings into another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, strcpy

I'm making a word search program in C which takes the user input and then chooses one of the global arrays of words and uses that to generate the word search. It works when I just use one of the global arrays but not with the choice, I want to copy the contents of the category arrays, depending on the users choice into the newArray which can be used with the word search. The program crashes after entering an option at the moment, here's what I have.

```
switch(choice)
{
    case 1: choseArray(newArray, massEffect);
    break;
    case 2: choseArray(newArray, fallout3);
    break;
    case 3: choseArray(newArray, elderScrolls);
    break;
    case 4: choseArray(newArray, gameOfThrones);
    break;
    case 5: choseArray(newArray, breakingBad);
    break;
    default: printf("Enter a valid option!");
}

void choseArray(char** newArray, char** category)
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<6;i++)
     {
         strcpy(newArray[i], category[i]);
     }
}
```

The arrays look like this and are declared globally for now

```
char gameOfThrones[6][250] = {"KINGSLANDING", "TYRIAN", "STARK", "LANISTERS", "WESTEROS", "WINTERFELL"};
char breakingBad[6][250] = {"JESSE", "WALT", "HEISENBERG", "SAUL", "GUSTAVO", "BREAKFAST"};
char newArray[6][250];
```

Comment: why not `void choseArray(char newArray[6][250], ....`  ?

Comment: You have not presented the declaration of `newArray` that applies in the scope of the `switch` statement, which is of great relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your word lists in this form ...

```
char gameOfThrones[6][250] = { ... };
```

then they are arrays of arrays of `char`s.  The function parameter type `char **` is a pointer to a `char` *pointer*, which is not even directly comparable.  Your compiler should have thrown a fit about this.

Supposing that `newArray` is of the same type as the base word lists, you should declare your function like so:

```
void choseArray(char newArray[][250], char category[][250]) { ... }
```

... or possibly like so:

```
void choseArray(char (*newArray)[250], char (*category)[250]) { ... }
```

... to match the actual argument types.  The body of your function probably works as-is in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much, got it working with that and I understand why now, i didn't get any compiler warning from devc++

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you get a compiler warning? Try declaring the function to match the arguments passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void choseArray(char newArray[][250], char category[][250]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        strcpy(newArray[i], category[i]);
}

int main()
{
    char gameOfThrones[6][250] = {"KINGSLANDING", "TYRIAN", "STARK", "LANISTERS", "WESTEROS", "WINTERFELL"};
    char breakingBad[6][250] = {"JESSE", "WALT", "HEISENBERG", "SAUL", "GUSTAVO", "BREAKFAST"};
    char newArray[6][250];
    choseArray(newArray, gameOfThrones);
    return 0;
}
```

The way you were doing it

```
char **newArray
```

is a pointer to a pointer, or, an array of pointers.